# Вывести объект по ключу MongoDB

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, mongodb-query

У меня есть такая коллекция :

```
{
   "MAIN":
   {
     "A":{row:"smth","Smth4example":"smth"},
     "B":{row:"smth2","Smth4example":"smth2"}
   }
}
```

Как мне вывести объект по ключу А :

```
{row:"smth","Smth4example":"smth"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильнее сделать такой запрос:

```
db.collectionName.find({"MAIN.A":{$exist: true}}, {_id:0, "MAIN.A":1})
```

Такой запрос вернет все поля A, со всех документов, в которых оно есть.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось вот так:

```
db.collectionName.distinct('MAIN.A')
```

Comment: Этот код действительно вернет поле А. Однако, если у Вас будет несколько документов с одинаковыми значениями, то вы об этом не узнаете, т.к. distinct их отфильтрует на уникальность